# Facebook messenger - Hyperlink response shown as text

Tags: facebook, messenger

I have integrated facebook messenger to my custom chat bot.
In response to facebook input from messenger, I have hyperlink/URLs, but
the response over facebook messenger is shown as text only. It's not converting it as hyperlink.

Response shown over facebook messenger as:
[image]

Where it should show as follows:
Amazon

Comment: Does the documentation say you can send HTML?

Comment: I searched, but haven't got any specific input. But yes I do got input where links are shared as text only.

Comment: You need to post plain text containing URLs, not HTML code containing links.

Comment: Yes, going ahead with same approach to send text containing URLs. Thanks